# How to extract some text from json file without loading it?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, jsonpath

`python` `lxml` can be used to extract text (e.g., with xpath) from XML files without having to fully parse XML. For example, I can do the following which is faster than BeautifulSoup, especially for large input. I'd like to have some equivalent code for JSON.

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.XML('<foo><bar>abc</bar></foo>')
print type(tree)
r = tree.xpath('/foo/bar')
print [x.tag for x in r]
```

I see http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/. But I don't see an example python code to extract some text from a json file without having use `json.load()`. Could anybody show me an example? Thanks.

Comment: Why you don't want to use 'json.load()' ?

Comment: I doubt that lxml works without actually parsing the XML file, basically because xpath methods always operate on a tree instance which is the parsed XML. The same concept should apply to JSON: parse, then access the element.

Comment: @zayn-ul-abdin `json.load()` takes time especially for large input.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you don't want to load the entire JSON for performance reasons.

If that's the case, perhaps [ijson](https://github.com/isagalaev/ijson) is what you need. I used it to search huge JSON files (>8gb) and it works well.

However, you will have to implement the search code yourself.